# join on string column containing numbers that have dissimilar format

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for some help.  I have no idea how to go about this.

I have two tables and I need to get data from ICD10Code column into the other ICD10Code column but the column I need to join on, ICD9Code, has some format differences where numbers are stored as string and trailing zeroes and decimal  are involved.

The 1st  table has columns  ReportingMeasure, ICD9Code, and ICD10Code.  The ICD10Code is null.  I need to populate ICD10Code from the 2nd table.

The 2nd  table has columns ICD9Code, and ICD10Code.  Now the problem.   Both columns are varchar(25) but table 1 doesn’t have trailing zeros and sometimes an integer has a trailing decimal and sometimes not.  Table 2 has trailing zeros and integers have a decimal and trailing zero.

```
TableST        TablePR
ICD9Code       ICD9Code
296.2          296.20
311. OR 311    311.0
```

This code works fine when there is a match but not for examples shown.

```
UPDATE TableST
SET ICD10Code = t2.ICD10Code
FROM TableST t1
INNER JOIN TablePR t2 ON t1.ICD9Code = t2.ICD9Code
GO
```

How do I go about updating the ICD10Code on rows with irregular ICD9Code?

Comment: You do know that a very large number of the ICD-9 Dx codes do not map directly to ICD-10? That's why the AMA publishes the GEM data, to assist in manual conversion of the many (many, many) ICD-9 codes that don't directly correlate to ICD-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the codes are always numbers, you can try joining on a decimal version:

```
on cast(t1.ICD9Code as decimal(10, 3)) = cast(t2.ICD9Code as decimal(10, 3))
```

The "3" is an arbitrary value for the maximum number of digits after the decimal place (it seems reasonable in this case).  Conversion to decimals is exact.  You would not want to use a floating point representation.

Another solution that might work in your case is to use `like`:

```
on t1.ICD9Code = t2.ICD9Code or
   ((t1.ICD9Code like '%.%' and t1.ICD9Code = t2.ICD9Code + '0') or
    (t1.ICD9Code not like '%.%' and t1.ICD9Code = t2.ICD9Code + '.0')
   )
```

Comment: That helped a little but not much.  For example one system has a code 305 and the other has it as 305.00.  They are numerically equivalent but don't join, even with the logic you recommended.  Not sure why that is.

I had high hope casting as decimal would work.

Comment: Your solution worked fine after all.  Turns out numbers like 305 weren't being added to the staging table.  Once I discovered that it all came together.  Thanks.